# different mock objects to compare objects in unit tests

Tags: c#, .net, xunit.net, xunit

I have Equals method that I am trying to tests. this method return true if object passed to is is same as this object.

I test true condition as following.

```
        var mocks = new MockRepository();
        var mockActionAlert = mocks.StrictMock<ActionAlert>();
        var mockActionAlert2 = mocks.StrictMock<ActionAlert>();
        bool comparer = mockActionAlert.Equals(mockActionAlert2);
        Assert.Equal(true, comparer);
```

However, how can I get a different mock object to test that equal method returns false.

Thank You,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have shown doesn't appear to make any sense at all.

You only have mocks in your test code - no real implementations at all.

Not only are you not testing anything real, but since you are using mocks, your can even decide whether your pretend tests should fail or not.

To do what (I think) you want, simply create an ActionAlert (one from you real code, not a mock of one) and then create a second ActionAlert with properties that should make it equal using your Equals method. Pass the second ActionAlert in and assert that the result is true (Probably best to use Assert.True() since that is more expressive of intent).

Then when testing that the Equals method returns false, write tests with ActionAlerts with properties that make them not equals. No need for mocks at all.

The place where you need mocks is where you have depenendencies in your classes under test that you want to either assert some behaviour on (has a dependence method been called in a certain way) or you want some predifined behaviour from (make a method return a certain value when called).

Comment: Aaah ok, that make sense. Let me try that. Thanks a lot :-)

Comment: yeah, that does it :-) I should really go back and change all my tests. I didn't really quiet know when to use mock objects and been mocking all over the place. Thanks for taking a time in explaining this.

Comment: @socialMatrix Glad I could be of help - have a look at this article http://martinfowler.com/articles/mocksArentStubs.html it is one on of the most useful articles written on mocks, by Martin Fowler who is one of the true gurus. Also, the mocking framework you are using will certainly have examples that will help you get the most out of using mocks. I remember when I first discovered mocking it changed the entire way I thought about testing code.